# Nuget Get latest package will fail on VSTS

Tags: nuget, azure-pipelines

I have multiple microservices and when my lib for fuzzy string search is updated then I have to open all projects and update.

So I went to project.json and made a change to version string. I changed that from a specific version to "*"

```
"dependencies": {
 /* was */
 "FuzzyString": "1.6.6267.27548",
 /* is now */
 "FuzzyString": "*",
```

Visual studio restored the package.

It's worth mentioning that I also have a nuget config file on a network share.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <packageSources>

    <add key="mycompany nuget" value="http://serverxyz/nuget/" />
    <add key="NuGet official package source" value="https://nuget.org/api/v3/" />
    <!-- <add key="MS and .NET" value="https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/curated-feeds/microsoftdotnet" /> -->
  </packageSources>
  <activePackageSource>

    <add key="mycompany nuget" value="http://serverxyz/nuget/" />
    <add key="NuGet official package source" value="https://nuget.org/api/v3/" />
    <!-- <add key="MS and .NET" value="https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/curated-feeds/microsoftdotnet" /> -->
  </activePackageSource>

</configuration>
```

And with all that, when restoring on VSTS it fails.

```
2017-03-01T09:12:59.1991601Z Restoring packages for C:\agent_work\10\s\abc\project.json...
2017-03-01T09:12:59.3141601Z   GET http://serverxyz/nuget/FindPackagesById()?id='FuzzyString'
2017-03-01T09:12:59.3291601Z   GET https://nuget.org/api/v3/FindPackagesById()?id='FuzzyString'
2017-03-01T09:12:59.4511601Z   OK http://serverxyz/nuget/FindPackagesById()?id='FuzzyString' 126ms
2017-03-01T09:12:59.4831601Z   GET http://serverxyz/api/v2/package/fuzzystring/1.6.6267.27548
2017-03-01T09:12:59.5181601Z   OK http://serverxyz/api/v2/package/fuzzystring/1.6.6267.27548 34ms
2017-03-01T09:13:00.5531601Z   NotFound https://nuget.org/api/v3/FindPackagesById()?id='FuzzyString' 1224ms
2017-03-01T09:13:00.5561601Z Retrying 'FindPackagesByIdAsyncCore' for source 'https://nuget.org/api/v3/FindPackagesById()?id='FuzzyString''.
2017-03-01T09:13:00.5561601Z Response status code does not indicate success: 404 (Not Found).
2017-03-01T09:13:00.5591601Z   GET https://nuget.org/api/v3/FindPackagesById()?id='FuzzyString'
2017-03-01T09:13:01.1441601Z   NotFound https://nuget.org/api/v3/FindPackagesById()?id='FuzzyString' 262ms
2017-03-01T09:13:01.1441601Z Retrying 'FindPackagesByIdAsyncCore' for source 'https://nuget.org/api/v3/FindPackagesById()?id='FuzzyString''.
2017-03-01T09:13:01.1451601Z Response status code does not indicate success: 404 (Not Found).
2017-03-01T09:13:01.1451601Z   GET https://nuget.org/api/v3/FindPackagesById()?id='FuzzyString'
2017-03-01T09:13:01.1461601Z   NotFound https://nuget.org/api/v3/FindPackagesById()?id='FuzzyString' 267ms
2017-03-01T09:13:01.1461601Z Failed to retrieve information from remote source 'https://nuget.org/api/v3/FindPackagesById()?id='FuzzyString''.
2017-03-01T09:13:01.1461601Z Response status code does not indicate success: 404 (Not Found).
2017-03-01T09:13:01.1461601Z Failed to retrieve information from remote source 'https://nuget.org/api/v3/FindPackagesById()?id='FuzzyString''.
2017-03-01T09:13:01.1461601Z   Response status code does not indicate success: 404 (Not Found).
2017-03-01T09:13:01.1561601Z ##[error]Error: C:\agent_work\_tasks\NuGetInstaller_333b11bd-d341-40d9-afcf-b32d5ce6f23b\0.2.29\node_modules\nuget-task-common\NuGet\3.5.0\NuGet.exe failed with return code: 1
2017-03-01T09:13:01.1561601Z ##[error]Packages failed to install
2017-03-01T09:13:01.1601601Z ##[section]Finishing: NuGet restore VerITStore.WebSite/VerITStore.WebSite.sln
```

I understand the 404 results because not all nuget servers have to contain the file but I don't agree this should indicate a fail because the other server contains the package.

How do I fix it?

Comment: What if you change the package source to `https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json`?

Comment: Funny. I would swear it worked with api/v3/. Now it only works with api/v2/

Comment: What's the result if you use dotnet-restore command https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/core/tools/dotnet-restore? Or can you share it in one dirve?